# Why doesn't converting constructor called in template class?

Tags: c++

I write a simple `C++` program:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B {
public:
    B(const bool& value = false) {cout << "B" << endl;} 
};

template <typename t1, typename t2>
class A {
public:
    A(const t1 &value) {cout << "A1" << endl;};
    A(const t2 &value) {cout << "A2" << endl;};
};

int main() {
    typedef A<B, int8_t> T;
    T v(false);

    return 0;
}
```

Per my understanding, in the following code:

```
T v(false);
```

`false` can trigger `B`'s converting constructor(`B(const bool& value = false) {cout << "B" << endl;}`) called, so the first `A`'s constructor should run. But in fact, the second `A`'s constructor is called.

So why doesn't converting constructor called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the first constructor would require a *user-defined* conversion from `bool` to `B`. Calling the second one would require a *standard* conversion from `bool` to `int8_t`.  The latter is a better match, which I think is pretty natural.

> **13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences**
>   **2** When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as defined in 13.3.3.1)
>    — a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and
>    — a user-defined conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2) is a better conversion sequence than an ellipsis conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.3).

Keep in mind that `bool` is considered an *integral* type in C++, so the conversion to `int8_t` is indeed a rather unremarkable conversion from one integral type to another. A user-defined conversion to a *class* is a much more involving process. It is not surprising that language rules favor the simple conversion to `int8_t`.